# Why don't we need to bind this function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bind, arrow-functions

I have this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/moj94s0e/1/

Where I'm playing with two ES6 Classes.

The first one is a simple class, with a constructor and a method (contains).

```
class Names {
  constructor (names) {
    this.names = names;
  }
  contains (names) {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

The second one is another Class (React component) that uses the contains a method of the first one:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.namesInstance = new Names(["Madrid", "Paris"]);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
   this.namesInstance.contains(["Madrid"]);
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

**My question is simple:** How is it possible that I have access to this in the contains method, considering it is not bound anywhere (nor in a constructor, in the call or declaring it with arrow function)?

If I change it to arrow function, I can see the Class Names logged into the console as well, including the contains method.

I don't understand this behavior.

If someone can help, please.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

They're intended for short function expressions in which it has no sense having its own site call scope and, moreover, it's much more handy to be able to access the external *this*.